# Watching a table in Parse.com

Tags: python, parse-platform

I am a bit new to python...I am trying to watch a table in parse.com. I want this function to run every 30 seconds and provide me the new results.. I have tryed the following code..

```
#A function for registring to parse 
from db_connect import register_to_parse 
from parse_rest.datatypes import Object as ParseObject 
import sys, threading 
appid = "hidden" 
restapi_key = "hidden" 
#registring to parse 
register_to_parse(appid, restapi_key)
#function to watch a table 
def tablewatcher():

    class UserResumeLog(ParseObject):
        pass
    threading.Timer(30.0, tablewatcher).start()

    findobjects=UserResumeLog.Query.filter(resumeUploaded=True,resumeParsed=False)
    return findobjects
```

I am able to retrieve the objectId the first time the function runs.. but if any new entries are added after i have start this function the code is not returning the results.. Can anyone please guide me on how to do it?

Comment: combination of `requests` and `bs4` would be perfect for this...

Comment: not sure what you're trying to achieve with these objects, but if you plan on just logging, or transforming them, look into background jobs! http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-background-jobs/

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response..  what i want to do is watch a table for new entries and trigger another process when a new entry is found...